# Java oq esse codigo faz?

Tags: javascript, java, java-8

Set conjunto = new TreeSet();

Aluno a = new Aluno("João da Silva", "Linux básico", 0);
Aluno b = new Aluno("Beto Barbosa", "OpenOffice", 0);
Aluno c = new Aluno("Lúcia Ferreira", "Internet", 0);
Aluno d = new Aluno("Beto Barbosa", "OpenOffice", 0);
conjunto.add(a);
conjunto.add(b);
conjunto.add(c);
conjunto.add(d);
System.out.println(conjunto);

[Linux básico, OpenOffice, Internet]

[João da Silva, Beto Barbosa,Lúcia Ferreira, Beto Barbosa]

[Beto Barbosa, Beto Barbosa, João da Silva, Lúcia Ferreira]

[Beto Barbosa, João da Silva, Lúcia Ferreira]

[Linux básico, OpenOffice, Internet, OpenOffice]

Comment: Aparentemente ele instancia objetos do tipo Aluno, que não é classe nativa, mas sim criada por alguém, e depois as adiciona ao TreeSet, que é semelhante a outros métodos de "coleção", mas ele é especifico (ou ideal) para trabalhar com ordenação, assim provavelmente você poderá ordenar sua lista de alunos baseado em algum critério que desejar. Note que Java e JavaScript não são a mesma coisa e não tem relação alguma.

Comment: Você [já postou essa dúvida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/566667/70). Importante seguir as orientações já dadas para viabilizar a postagem dentro do site, editando sua postagem original. Para evitar duplicação de orientações, os comentários foram desativados aqui, mas estão funcionais [na postagem original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/566342/70).